# MongoDB: find records for last X days (in strict JSON)

Tags: json, mongodb, strict

Finding records for last X days only can be done in **mongo Shell Mode** with

```
db.some_collection.find({"some_date":{$gte: (newDate((newDate()).getTime() - (X * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))}})
```

My question: is there a **strict JSON** equivalent to this command or not?

Comment: Please give more details. It’s difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question vague, incomplete and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: @Sourabh mLC is asking how can we do strict JSON search by time in Mongo. Since `newDate` is not JSON friendly, mLC is asking for a JSON friendly alternative to `newDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would much rather have this be false but it seems like there is no way to do a strict JSON search for datetime in mongo. You might want to store time as a string (unix timestamp) and then search for it like a string or use non JSON query with date object

Comment: That's unfortunate but what can we do.